# type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Recently I got this type problem from my codes. Here have two type of problems. First problem is `type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'bool'` this is the problem. And Second Problem is `A RenderFlex overflowed by 99535 pixels on the bottom.` This is the two type of problem i am faced. I don't understand where is the problem. So for that reason I will be put my all codes here.

Here is the Problem Log.

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═══════════════════════════════

A RenderFlex overflowed by 99535 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column 
lib/partials/myclients.dart:31
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════

type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<List<MyClient>> 
lib/partials/myclients.dart:63
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is my Screen page.
MyClientPage Screen

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyClentsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClentsPageState createState() => _MyClentsPageState();
}

class _MyClentsPageState extends State<MyClentsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  MyClient myClient = MyClient();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // MyPerformChart(),
          // Text("Quick Performance checker"),
          // PerformDataList(),
          searchBar(),
          dataListView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding searchBar() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          hintText: 'Search By Name',
        ),
        controller: searchController,
        onChanged: (value) {
          print(value);
        },
        onSubmitted: (value) {
          searchController.text = value;
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget dataListView() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<MyClient>>(
      future: myClient.fetchClients(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List leads = snapshot.data;
          return dataList(leads);
        } else if (snapshot.error) {
          // print(snapshot.error);
          return Text("You have no clients");
        }

        return CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Expanded dataList(List<MyClient> data) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          primary: false,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final MyClient client = data[index];
            return LeadComponent(client);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I think here have problem but where i am not understanding about this.
MyClient Model

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:PandeetApp/services/myclient.dart';

class MyClient extends MyClientService {
  final int id, clientId, acceptedBy, pincode;
  final double latitude, longitude;
  final String perpose,
      details,
      when,
      name,
      mobile,
      email,
      orgName,
      address,
      city,
      state,
      country,
      clientIp,
      device,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt;

  MyClient({
    this.id,
    this.clientId,
    this.perpose,
    this.details,
    this.when,
    this.acceptedBy,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.email,
    this.orgName,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.pincode,
    this.clientIp,
    this.device,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory MyClient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MyClient(
      id: json['id'],
      clientId: json['client_id'],
      perpose: json['perpose'],
      details: json['details'],
      when: json['when'],
      acceptedBy: json['accepted_by'],
      name: json['name'],
      mobile: json['mobile'],
      email: json['email'],
      orgName: json['org_name'],
      address: json['address'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      pincode: json['pincode'],
      country: json['country'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      clientIp: json['client_ip'],
      device: json['device'],
      createdAt: json['created_at'],
      updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
    );
  }

  Future<List<MyClient>> fetchClients() async {
    var datas = await super.fetchDatas();
    List dataList = jsonDecode(datas);

    return dataList.map((e) => MyClient.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

This is the API Services Part Where I am Linked API Part here. May It will be needed to be understand the codes.

MyClient Service

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:PandeetApp/config/app.dart' as app;

class MyClientService {
  Future fetchDatas() async {
    var panditId = 1;
    var url = app.myclientsUrl + '?pid=$panditId';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = response.body;
      return data;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load jobs from API');
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you to all.

Comment: Please consider being as specific as you can, adding context, your attempts (very important!), your understanding.... And don't hurry people to help you. Please, improve your question, else it might get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List leads = snapshot.data;
          return dataList(leads);
        } else if (snapshot.error) {
          // print(snapshot.error);
          return Text("You have no clients");
        }
```

It should be this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List leads = snapshot.data;
          return dataList(leads);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // print(snapshot.error);
          return Text("You have no clients");
        }
```

Also instead of this:

```
Expanded dataList(List<MyClient> data) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          primary: false,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final MyClient client = data[index];
            return LeadComponent(client);
          }),
    );
  }
```

You have to give a fixed height to ListViewBuilder:

```
Container dataList(List<MyClient> data) {
    return Container(
      height: 350,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          primary: false,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final MyClient client = data[index];
            return LeadComponent(client);
          }),
    );
  }
```

Otherwise, It would overflow and doesn't display anything.

Comment: Updated answer please check

Comment: Thank you friend. You are really awesome. I already approved.